# How do we track the growth of a team?

Tags: team, productivity

I want to make my team productive and growing at a rapid pace. What are the factors I should consider while evaluating the progress of my team in that (or any other relevant) direction?

Comment: First, define "growth"..

Answer (score 3):

This is how I evaluate the growth and performance of my team:

1. **Are they communicating well enough or not.** A good team has excellent communication amongst themselves. So, for keeping a track of this, one has to have a messaging medium like Slack, Hipchat, etc.
2. **Deadlines:** I'm not really a fan of tight deadlines and making people in my team work on them, but yeah, a highly productive team try to achieve deadlines as frequently as possible.

Comment: I would think a good team is one that meets deadlines 100% of the time, managements job is to make sure they have achievable deadlines, teams job is to achieve them. How well they communicate with the manager and vice versa is also vital to analysing their growth.... in my opinion

Answer (score 2):

GRK,

The first question to ask, is what is the mission of the team. That is, how does your team fit in the overall mission of the department, or company? In your question, you state you would like your team to grow.

Some things to think about:

- How does YOUR manager view the role of your team, and does the business allow for it to grow?
- How can you better align yourself with the business, to create more demand, thus enable the growth you are seeking?
- How can you ensure that when called-upon, the team can/will deliver these results? This takes top performers and other members who seek continuous improvement and a manager to help drive it.

I hope you are successful, I didn't mean to turn your question back on you, but a lot really depends on the purpose for your team existing within the business.

If you are actually looking to help your team improve their performance, setting yearly goals and providing FREQUENT feedback is very important. Help them understand how their work contributes, and invite them to help you grow. It's better if you're not the only one thinking about growth.

Personal growth by taking classes,etc. is important for the development of the individual team members, and anything you can do to pay for classes, training, etc. will only help accelerate their performance.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to deadlines: track "cadance" against a burn-down list of (approximately) sized and prioritized tasks. See various Agile methodologies, including but not limited to Scrum.

Answer (score 0):

I have four main criteria when judging a teams all around performance and growth over time which break down roughly as follows.

1) How well they work together, do they communicate well between themselves, is anyone bottlenecking the work and no one is addressing the issue? Do they help each other?

2) Communication with their manager, is the relationship a strong productive one, do they step up and take responsibility for their issues and look for resolutions proactively? Or do they leave problems until it becomes a struggle to fix them and then do a lot of unconstructive finger pointing.

3) Quality of their work, is the quality and speed improving, am I consistently receiving positive feedback from clients or negative, or none? How do they handle crisis, confidently or not?

4) Ambition, are any of the team member showing leadership qualities, not necessarily in terms of leading projects, also in terms of upgrading or acquiring new qualifications and/or skills.

Looking at these areas gives a pretty good idea of how the team is improving or deteriorating and if I saw a marked decrease in any of these areas I would be concerned. One of my main watermarks might seem unrelated but works for me. 'How do they handle crisis situations, confidently or not?'. This is a measure of professionalism and experience that shows up under stress and is useful to take heed of, over time they should handle crisis situation markedly better. If they don't then their confidence in their own abilities might be lacking. Or their confidence in their colleagues abilities might be lacking.